# iOS capturing audio via jack port

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I know ios audio programming can route the audio signal to headphone jack port instead the speakers.

But How to treat the headphone jack port as input mic (and be able to capture the signal)?

is that possible?

this is what I need

[cool video explaining what I need](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsQiDDhZLDU)

[image]

thanks in advance
Dario

Comment: [this link][1] proves that it' possible


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002133/forcing-iphone-microphone-as-audio-input/4994901#4994901

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a nice demonstration project about using Audio Queue Services

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html

I would suggest going through this project, and it should show you what you need.

Comment: this is what I need.

http://www.google.it/imgres?um=1&hl=en&client=firefox-a&sa=N&rls=org.mozilla:it:official&biw=1280&bih=636&tbm=isch&tbnid=juKK0mO1uAHehM:&imgrefurl=http://www.iusecomputer.com/better-iphone-audio-amp-video-adapters-microphones-and-accessories-for-superior-sound-iphone.html&docid=AeXhx3Gu8s5iQM&imgurl=http://www.iusecomputer.com/cache/KM-IPHONE-MIC-3.jpeg%253F323f2c&w=500&h=332&ei=TvdRUMWxDcrV4QTA_YDgBg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=448&vpy=157&dur=1807&hovh=183&hovw=276&tx=148&ty=84&sig=111075682610986459140&page=1&tbnh=123&tbnw=185&start=0&ndsp=18&ved=1t:429,r:2,s:0,i:79

Comment: I tried the app at the link you mentioned, but the sound check on my iPad with a mic plugged in the jack audio covering the iPad mic doesn't record anything.

Comment: your link doesn't fit what I need

Comment: You will need to use Audio Queue Services to do this, the project doesnt go in depth in exactly what you need to do. That requires some of your own knowledge to get that done. I would suggest you pickup a book like this http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Core-Audio-Hands-On-Programming/dp/0321636848

Comment: ok, thanks. I already have the book. I am new in this Core Audio programming and I'll try to make it works. thanks atrljoe for your help! The important thing is that it's possible to do!